# Struggles with connecting to my cloud storage on the Wi-Fi network

Tags: router, wireless-router, ethernet, mesh-networking

I have the following setup:

Fiber router/modem with my Desktop connected via Ethernet and a TP-link Deco E4 Wi-Fi main unit connected to modem via Ethernet.
All my Wi-Fi devices are on the Deco mesh network. [Network Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCFab.jpg)

The problem I am having is with the MyCloud storage I connected to the main Deco.
The subnet on the fiber modem is 192.168.1.x where my desktop is 192.168.1.3 and my Deco main unit is 192.168.1.15
However - in the setup of the Deco its IP says 192.168.68.1 and all devices connected to it has IPs for the same subnet of 192.168.68.100 to 192.168.68.200 - this is the default settings.  The MyCloud storage IP address it has now when connected via ethernet to the Deco is 192.168.68.113
I would like to keep the MyCloud unit on the Deco so that my other laptops, TVs and cell phones can connect to it to stream media.

When I tried to put the LAN IP of the Deco from 192.168.68.x to 192.168.1.x I am getting an error stating that the WAN and LAN addresses cannot be in the same subnet.

As far as my limited goes, I need to have the desktop and devices connected to the Deco Wi-Fi unit to be in the same subnet to allow my desktop to communicate with my cloud storage.

I also diasbled my modem Wi-Fi and only have the Wi-Fi from the Deco system active.

What can I do to solve this issue?  I made contact with the TP-link technical dept, but am yet to receive any feedback...

I have limited knowledge of this, so any help will be truly appreciate.

Is there any way I can access my cloud storage with the current setup without plugging it into the modem itself?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you.  My PC was connected directly to my router.  However, all other devices including my Mycloud EX 4100 were connected to the Deco Mesh network (192.168.68.XX)

You need to be on the same LAN as the Mycloud device in order to access it.

Solution I used:
I connected a switch to the Main Deco unit that is connected to the router. I then connected my PC to the Deco unit.

Once that was done, my PC obtained an IP address in the 192.168.68.XX range and I was able to access the dashboard.

Hope this helps.